# How to turn off all sphinx latex formatting and use custom latex style file

Tags: python-sphinx

In my workflow, the PDF output is more important than the HTML output.
I have read the docs section [here](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/latex.html) that outlines latex customization but wanted to ask this general question to see what others did.

I have a latex style file that i use for my current template and am looking for a way to "plug-n-play" this style file with sphinx. The latex style is pretty complicated so ideally, I can turn off all sphinx latex style and class files, and just use mine. I'm aware this might not be possible but am wondering what my options are?

I looked at the `latex_additional_files` argument and it looks promising.

TL;DR: i have a highly customized latex style file that i would like to use effortlessly with sphinx.